# 'requires string as left operand, not list' searching for keywords and printing relative lines from a txt file

Tags: python

So I'm making a phone trouble shooter for a project at school and I'm always receiving the error

> TypeError: 'in string' requires string as left operand, not list

I'm really confused as I have no idea what to do and the code looks fine to me. Here it is:

```
sq = input("What is wrong")
word = sq.split()
with open("solutions.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if word in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+20]: print(l),
        print
```

Could someone please tell me how to get this piece of code to return the multiple relative lines according to the keyword? Thanks.

Comment: `word = sq.split()` is a list

Comment: Yeah I know, so I can't get it to work, any idea on any alternatives?

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. This is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). From your description it is unclear whether you want to look for a single or word multiple words (and in that case, all or any of them)

Comment: I'm only looking for a single keyword that identifies the users problem

Comment: alright, then (as described in my answer below), isn't your code working if you just substitute `word = sq.split()` with `word = sq.strip()` ? Assuming only one keyword is entered (whitespaces as prefix/suffix are allowed)

Comment: no, it's not only 1 keyword, the user inputs a sentence, such as 'I can't make calls'. I must then identify the key word, in this case any solution regarding to 'call'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sq = 'hello how are you'
word = sq.split()
print(type(word))
print(word)
```

produces

```
<class 'list'>
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

So `word` is a list (and should really be named `words` ;) )

So with

```
if word in line:
```

the code is checking a list is inside each line (which is a string), instead of checking a single word (i.e. a string) is.

I ignore what you want to look for in the file, presumably any of the words entered

```
            if any(w in line for w in word): 
                for l in searchlines[i:i+20]: print(l),
                print
```

or all of the words entered

```
            if all(w in line for w in word): 
                for l in searchlines[i:i+20]: print(l),
                print
```

or maybe you are expecting a single word and just wanted to make sure the whitespace is stripped off

```
word = sq.strip()
```

Comment: if any(w in line for w in word): 
                for l in searchlines[i:i+20]: print(l),
                print                                                                                                              This worked for me, but now if the user types 'my memory management is poor', all the results for 'is' and its following lines appear, when all I need is just the 'memory' part of it. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: how would you identify `memory` in such a string. Please describe your requirements exhaustively

Comment: idek, i just need to find the keyword that identifies the users problem, thereby letting me print the solution

Answer (score 0):

`word` is assigned in your line 2 as a list. but line 6

```
if word in line
```

required `word` to be a `string` this is the problem

To answer your question of how to

> get this piece of code to return the multiple relative lines
>   according to the keyword

Please define "multiple relative lines according to the keyword"

Comment: so I have a txt file with all the solutions for the problems that the user may encounter. I need to search the txt file for the keyword (for example, the might write 'my screen is frozen', I need to look for screen in my txt file and print the solution